# how to add required validator for ng-select in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm using angular 7 and ng-select (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select) module to display select with options. I want required validation for that field.  I'm using angular reactive form.

Below is the code

```
 <ng-select [searchable]="false" formControlName="testName" required>
      <ng-option [value]="true">Yes</ng-option>
       <ng-option [value]="false">No</ng-option>
 </ng-select>
```

And ts code

```
this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      testName: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

But when I click on submit button it does not show the error message.
I'm aware of angular 7 validations but I'm looking specific with ng-select.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply required validation to dropdown in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943150/how-to-apply-required-validation-to-dropdown-in-angular-2)

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha I'm looking specific for ng-select library

Answer (score 0):

Angular FormField functionality can still be used with the said library, is this something you are looking for?

```
 <ng-select [searchable]="false" formControlName="testName" required>
      <ng-option [value]="true">Yes</ng-option>
       <ng-option [value]="false">No</ng-option>
 </ng-select> 
<span *ngIf=testForm.get('testName').errors?.required?>Please fill this field</span>


<button [disabled]="testForm.invalid">the submit button </button>
```